# Can't change locale for rails app when running in Heroku works well in development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, heroku

I have an bilingual app in development. I can change the locale to english in development by passing ?locale=en, it works in development but not in heroku.

By the logger i inserted below I can tell the locale actually changes but all the content is emitted in the default locale

application_controller.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery
  before_filter :set_locale

  def set_locale    
    if %w(en pt-BR).include? params[:locale]
      I18n.locale = params[:locale].to_sym
    end
    logger.info I18n.locale
  end
end
```

config/application.rb

```
config.i18n.default_locale = :'pt-BR'
config.i18n.locale = :'pt-BR'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery
  before_filter :set_locale

  protected    
  def set_locale
    if params[:locale].blank?
      I18n.locale = :'pt-BR'
    else
      I18n.locale = params[:locale]
    end
  end   

  # ensure locale persists
  def default_url_options(options={})
    {:locale => I18n.locale}
  end
end
```

and in routes.rb

```
  scope "(:locale)", :locale => /pt-BR|en/ do
    resources :products  # update this!
  end
```

It feels cleaner to have `domain.tld/:locale/` type routing as well.